# SCVMM 2012 console addin execution

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, powershell, add-in

I'm developing an SCVMM 2012 console Add-In.

The SDK documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860311.aspx

But the documentation has no info on threading or how the add-in gets executed at all.

Now here's what I have:

```
public class SomeAddIn : ViewAddInBase
{ 
private bool gotServerInfo = false;
private bool gotConnectionString = false;
public override FrameworkElement CreateViewControl()
    {
    GetServerInfo();
    GetConnectionString();
    if(gotServerInfo && gotConnectionString)
    {
     return GetGoodFrameworkElement(); //do some stuff to fill FrameworkElement
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to DB, returning empty screen...");
    return new FrameworkElement();
    }

    private void GetServerInfo()
    {
    PowerShellContext.ExecuteScript<ServerConnection>("Get-SCVMMServer localhost",
    (items, error) =>
        {
            // code to set server info here
            if (error == null)
            {
                gotServerInfo = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Got settings from server.");
            }
            else{//Error}
        });
    }
    private void GetConnectionString()
    {
    //PowerShell connect to database, get connection string
    gotConnectionString = true; //if got string
    }
}
```

Looks all good, but the problem is that `powershell` commands take time to execute and the "`return new FrameworkElement();`" gets executed first before `gotServerInfo` and `gotConnectionString` get set to true.

My guess is that VMM starts multiple threads for my methods and the execution of those is not sequential anymore. How do I get VMM to execute my methods in the right order?

What I've tried to do:

1) use threads for my methods, set priority to high, set current
    thread priority to low or even as background, yet this doesn't help.
    Thread.Join doesn't work either.

2) move my methods to "`public override void OnLoad()` or
    `OnShow()`. The `CreateViewControl()` gets executed first anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to the problem occurring during initialization, but I moved on to MVVM (WPF) and a separate threading model. After you get the basic interface up, it's up to you what you want to do and how to synchronize everything. VMM latter acts as a usual WPF application giving you one main thread for the interface. Use ThreadPool class for dispatching background tasks - found it's the easiest way to do it.